# CSS remove white space around image

Tags: html, css, image, layout

I'm using an image from Amazon directly on my website, so I can't manually trim it in an image editing program.
Around the image is lots of white space, which is annoying because under this image, there is text. And this makes the **gap between the image and the text under it** really big (because of said white space at the bottom of the image).

Also, every image contains a different amount of white space, so I can't just set a fixed negative `margin-bottom`.

I know that `mix-blend-mode: multiply;` makes the white space transparent, but the gap is still there because the white (now transparent part) still takes up space in the layout.

How do I make the white part go away so other html elements can use that space?

Here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/AlessioG/pen/VweqMEg

Comment: Could you add codepen in here.

Comment: @Frontendemployee I've added a codepen. Tried to add some CSS values of my own website to make the situation more similar, even though most of them are not necessary

Comment: No, please do not add a codepen. Instead, add a [mcve] **in** the question itself. This question will lose any value to future visitors if codepen is inaccessible, and SO has the same embedded executable question functionality

Comment: @AlessioGravili Did you find any solution

Answer (score 1):

If you have a CSS you can assign the img a display block.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the object-fit css property to crop the image.

Set the container div to the cropped size that you want the image to be, and set the image to that same width and height, then use object-fit on the image.

```
<div id="crop-container">
    <img id="crop-image">
</div>

#crop-container {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}

#crop-image {
    object-fit:cover;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
```

Comment: try making object-fit from cover to none, and just set the width and height to the picture that you're trying to "crop"

Comment: That works for one image, but sadly not for other images with different sizes. They all have to share the same CSS code :/

Answer (score 0):

Just use object-fit and then assign a higher number to width than height in proportion. Please dont use element names like div p or id names etc. Since it is pretty hard to overwrite that.

```css
.image {
  margin: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
}

.header-two {
  margin: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
  <img class="image" src="https://i.imgur.com/l2QrzBg.jpg">
  <h2 class="header-two">This is a text</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: That works for one image, but sadly not for other images with different sizes. They all have to share the same CSS code :/

Comment: The different images are automatically generated by a plugin, so that'd be too time-consuming.

Comment: Write a JavaScript function that will do that for you